# Drupal Search API module with taxonomy filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-modules, drupal-search

I have three content types with a taxonomy Term field "Topics". I want to create a Drupal search with Search API module.
For the users I want to expose a search textfield and Topics as Dropdown so that they can select taxonomy topics and search for a keyword in that Topic.
But with the search api module I am not seeing an option to expose my taxonomy Term field as drop down field.
Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

check Facets API module and Taxonomy Facets

I think this can help

https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_facets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found that I can get this functionality using search_api_views module. But I am finding difficulty to get auto suggestions from the search api text field. I used Search API auto complete module. But that module is not taking the taxonomy filter values for narrowing the results. It is only considering the value given in the search text field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Taxonomies are indexed from your index FIELDS tab.Then you can create exposed filters on taxonomies in your view on index."Taxonomy Facets" module also can help.

Answer (score 0):

Facet API suggested in other answer is for Drupal 7. The [Facets module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) in Drupal 8 enables your website with faceted searching abilities. Facets also supports Drupal 9.

You can display your facets in blocks.